# Textarea background conflicts with its placeholder background-image on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Textarea background conflicts with its placeholder background-image on IE

I am trying to put a placeholder with an image but something annoying happens when being viewed in IE. Chrome, Firefox, Edge and even Opera correctly displayed the textarea's background with the placeholder image while IE is not okay at all.

Well this is what happening, the textarea's background is being ignored while the placeholder background image is being rendered first. I want it that both the background color of the textarea and the placeholder background shows correctly as this being the case on other browsers.

Please take a better look of my code on this jsbin:

https://jsbin.com/zajobog/9/edit?html,css,output

```css
.textarea {
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.textarea textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: #787878;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
}
.textarea textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}
.textarea textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}
.textarea textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}
.textarea textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}
.textarea textarea::placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left 15px;
  background-size: contain;
}
.textarea textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px 20px;
}
.textarea textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left top;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
.textarea textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left top;
  background-position: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="textarea">
  <textarea placeholder="      This is a sample placeholder"></textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there are a lot of workarounds using js maybe but a good explanation of what is going on with this is what I need.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. How is it supposed to be displayed, and how is it currently being displayed on Internet Explorer?

Comment: The sample code above works perfectly in chrome/firefox/edge. Try to open the jsbin link I have above on IE and you will see the difference. On IE, the background I have in textarea don't show unless it is focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `!important` flag to override the background color and define border color in IE 11:

```
.textarea textarea {
     ...
     border: 1px solid #787878;
     background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
     ...
}
```

You could check the complete example below and it works in IE 11:

```css
.textarea {
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.textarea textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #787878;
  background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
}

.textarea textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}

.textarea textarea:-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}

.textarea textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}

.textarea textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(235, 100, 77, 0.43);
}

.textarea textarea::placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left 15px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.textarea textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px 20px;
}

.textarea textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left top;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

.textarea textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  background: url(https://static.stickerjapan.com/v2/images/sticky/icon-comment.svg) no-repeat left top;
  background-position: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea">
  <textarea placeholder="      This is a sample placeholder."></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I never thought adding !important will fix this.